# Java AES with 32 bytes length initialize vector

Tags: java, php

I want to recive same encrypting result by using AES with PHP and JAVA 
but in PHP `mcrypt` need 32 bytes length Initialize vector and in Java i can use only 16 bytes length IV (`Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Wrong IV length: must be 16 bytes long`)even with unlimited strength policy how coudl i make compatible Java AES with PHP ?

```
$cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, '', 'ctr', '');
$iv_size = mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($cipher);

$key = '***';
$iv =  hex2str('00000001040506070000000000000001');


// Encrypt
if (mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, $key, $iv) != -1)
{
    $encrypted = mcrypt_generic($cipher, $text);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);

    echo '<strong>After encryption:</strong> ' . bin2hex($encrypted) . '<br />';
}
```

in java im using `encryptCipher =
               Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/PKCS5Padding")`

Comment: PHP's AES, aka rijndael-128, requires a 16-byte IV. Are you certain you've got the right algorithm?

Comment: i have posted some of my code

Comment: I'm not a Java expert, but I think you've got the wrong algo there. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9334357/1064767) to extract a listing out of your system. Also, I'm not a crypto expert, but you probably shouldn't post your keys on the internet. :I

Comment: I don't think you can use only 16 bytes length IV in java. Why are you not posting you java code clearly as you are doing with php while your question is on java.