# How do I use 'PBEWithHmacSHA1AndDESede' with Jasypt?

Tags: java, encryption, jce, hmacsha1

I am using [Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/) in a linux bash script where I want to encrypt a text string with the algorithm *PBEWithHmacSHA1AndDESede*. When running the command:

```
./encrypt.sh input="This is my message to be encrypted" password=MYPAS_WORD verbose=false algorithm=PBEWITHHMACSHA1ANDDESEDE
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBEWITHHMACSHA1ANDDESEDE SecretKeyFactory not available
```

According to this [link](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Using_the_Java_Cryptographic_Extensions), PBEWithHmacSHA1AndDESede is included in SunJCE. My assumption is that SunJCE is included in the latest JDK. Is this correct? If not, how can I download the SunJCE jar file?

Comment: Do you have your JDK from Oracle? [Check yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9333504/1816580) if it's there. Maybe you have multiple JRE's. Which is the public JRE?

Comment: You really shouldn't be using DES (or 3DES) nowadays it's slower and less secure than AES.

Comment: @artjom-b `java -version`
`java version "1.8.0_73"`
`Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_73-b02)`
`Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.73-b02, mixed mode)`
`javac -version`
`javac 1.8.0_73`

Comment: @artjom-b I know that DES is no longer secured, unfortunately I need to use this particular algorithm for compatibility with another app.

Comment: I've installed BouncyCastle but the only two supported algorithms that start with PBEWITHHMACSHA1 are PBEWITHHMACSHA1ANDAES_128 and PBEWITHHMACSHA1ANDAES_256.