# Java SecretKeyFactory not availale

Tags: java, security, private-key, java-security

I am trying to generate a private key with a password using a SecretKeyFactory and when I start the program I have a runtime exception that says algorithm not available. But in others PCs it works fine! Any help ?

```
private static void generatePrivateKey(String pwd) {

    try {
        PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(pwd.toCharArray());
        SecretKeyFactory kf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128");
        PRIVATE_KEY = kf.generateSecret(keySpec);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Runtime exception:
[image]

Comment: do you know the specific JRE that the other PCs have that do have the PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128? You are currently using JRE 1.8.0_121 and perhaps it's not supported for that environment. Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333504/how-can-i-list-the-available-cipher-algorithms to list the available algorithms

Comment: Yes the other PC have JRE 1.8.0_121 and it runs very well

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possibilities:

1. May be the JRE has been modified
2. An additional crypto provider has been installed. As you don't specify the provider in your ScretKeyFactory creation you don't know which provider is used. In Oracle JRE the algorithm you want is provided by the SunJCE. hence the following should work: `SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128", "SunJCE");`

Comment: in that way, I hava another runtime exception: " java.security.NoSuchProviderException: no such provider: SunJCE "

Comment: Then the JRE is non-standard or manipulated. Deinstall it and load the current version from Oracle.

Comment: I do that too, and the problem persist. I install the last java 8 verion